# How to restrict a custom databound control to accept my custom collection as datasource?

Tags: .net, asp.net, custom-controls, databound

I have created a custom databound control as per my requirements and now I want to restrict this control should take custom collection as datasource instead of every collection which is impelmented IEnuberable interface.

Is it possible to restrict? If yes, how to restrict this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Can you put a guard in the setter of DataSource ?

```
public object DataSource
{
  get
  {
    return ....;
  }
  set
  {
    if (value is typeof(myCollection) ) 
        this.dataSource = value;
    else
       throw InvalidOperationException("DataSource must by {0}" typeof(myCollection).FullName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way is to put the type check in Data Source related properties. For example, @Preet has already pointed out overriding `DataSource` setter. Only issue with the approach, that you need to also take care of a situation where the control is bound using `DataSourceID`.

I will rather recommend putting a type check in [DataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol.performdatabinding.aspx) method - this is of course assuming that you have inherited from `DataBoundControl` class. This method gets called so that derived class can actually bound the data - so it stands as a good candidate. Another equivalent is to put check in `OnDataBind`.

Yet another way is to expose specific collection as a property to accept the data. In such case, you should avoid exposing `DataSource` related properties.